# How to get multiple names in a jQuery element selector?

Tags: jquery

i want to apply my script on multiple pages so the var should read 3 names not just one;
this is how it looks now:

```
var first;
$(document).ready(function() {
  first = $('[name=body]').val();
});
```

need to do an or " || " or an and " && " some how so the name could be 'body','body2' and 'body3', depends on what page is it.
please help

Thanks all,

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can list multiple items in the selector, like this:

```
var body;
$(function() {
   body = $('[name=body], [name=body2], [name=body3]').val();
});
```

Answer (score 11):

Why not cover all eventualities, using the attribute-starts-with selector (`attribute^="value"`):

```
var first;
$(document).ready(function() {
    first = $('[name^="body"]').val();
});
```

Bear in mind that this will search all elements for that particular attribute/value; so it's better to restrict the amount of work the browser has to do, for example by identifying a particular element-type:

```
first = $('input[name^="body"]');
```

Also, as the selector returns an array the `val()` will be taken from the *first* matching element returned by the selector, it won't return an array of the values from all the matched elements.

References:

- [attribute-starts-with (`attribute^="value"`)selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast response, it's not only body, i have also other names like message for example.

Answer (score 0):

check my snippet

```
$('a[name="' + href + '"]' + ', a[name="' + decodeURIComponent(href) + '"]');
```

and the generated `selector` will be like

```
'a[name="May%2FJune"], a[name="May/June"]"'
```

Answer (score 0):

David Thomas answer works. I only want to mention if you want tp get all values at once (e.g. for an ajax call) you could use the serialize function which will give you a urlencoded string which you could use in the ajax functions of jQuery or any other url-based functions (e.g. window.location.href)

```
all = $('input[name^="body"]').serialize;
```